# Question about a recursive definition of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Consider the algorithm below.

[image]
[image]

Applying the given algorithm above to $A_{11} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 8\end{pmatrix},\ B_{11} = \begin{pmatrix}7 & 1 \\ 5 & 9\end{pmatrix}$ we get $A_{\color{red}{11}} = 1, \ A_{\color{red}{12}} = 2, \ A_{\color{red}{21}} = 3, \ A_{\color{red}{22}} = 8, \ B_{\color{blue}{11}} = 7, \ B_{\color{blue}{12}} = 1, \ B_{\color{blue}{21}} = 5, \ B_{\color{blue}{22}} = 9$ which are $1 \times 1$ so we must apply the base case to them which is $c_{11} = a_{11} \cdot b_{11} + c_{11}$. But how do we apply the base case to these $1 \times 1$ matrices? Ignoring the base case and simply applying the matrix multiplication procedure to these integers produces the correct answer, but shouldn't we fall back to the base case when $n = 1$? Does the base case only apply to the originally given matrices and not those gotten from applying the recursive steps?

Comment: Warning !!! You work on an erroneous (truncated) copy of the algorithm given on slide 6 of this slideshow : https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1415/AdvAlgo/lec4_ann.pdf. You need adding the results of the recursive calls !

Comment: @JeanMarie, I see. But even there the base case is the same and I come up against the same problem.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not the comment I was awaiting ; **you cannot leave this erroneous algorithm as it is** ; has it been given to you like this ? I imagine there are some lines more...

Comment: @JeanMarie, the algo you linked to is from the third edition of Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein. The one in my OP is from the newer 4th edition of the same book.  In the latter one the matrix multiplication procedure is implicit in the recursive step whereas in the 3rd ed it's more explicit. From the 4th ed: (1) https://ibb.co/9qh2fbP and (2) https://ibb.co/5RfyQHF. These equations are just regular matrix multiplication procedure.

Comment: As I understand from your comment, it is  "multiply and add" procedures ? Right ?

Comment: That's correct.